# Reading/Parsing Command-Line Arguments in C; binary and decimal conversions

Tags: c, binary, command-line-arguments

I have to write a program in C that reads and parses different command-line arguments but I have no idea where to start. All I have write now is the usage:

```
usage:
binary OPTION SIZE NUMBER
OPTION:
-b NUMBER is binary and output will be in decimal.
-d NUMBER is decimal and output will be in binary.
SIZE:
-8 input is an unsigned 8-bit integer.
-16 input is an unsigned 16-bit integer.
-32 input is an unsigned 32-bit integer.
-64 input is an unsigned 64-bit integer.
NUMBER:
number to be converted.
```

Other than this, I am not sure how to get user input and go about with the conversions. Any help would be great!

Comment: You might want [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html)

Comment: Is `binary` itself also an argument? And what exactly are you hoping here with this question; asking somebody to just spit out the programme? Not that we can't, but we shouldn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the following code-snippet and work it on from there, but please note:

1. I do not see any need to make use of the `SIZE` argument. If this argument is essential for your exercise (or any other reason behind this question), then you'll need to think how you want to use it.
2. I do not perform any assertion on the input number, so the code below assumes a legal decimal input number when `OPTION = -d` and a legal binary input number when `OPTION = -d`.
3. There is probably more than one way to implement it, and the code below is merely an example.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned long long str_to_ull(char* str,int base)
{
    int i;
    unsigned long long ull = 0;
    for (i=0; str[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        ull *= base;
        ull += str[i]-'0';
    }
    return ull;
}

void print_ull(unsigned long long ull,int base)
{
    if (ull/base > 0)
        print_ull(ull/base,base);
    printf("%d",ull%base);
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    char* OPTION;
    char* SIZE  ;
    char* NUMBER;

    unsigned long long number = 0;

    if (argc < 4)
    {
        printf("Missing input arguments\n");
        return -1;
    }

    OPTION = argv[1];
    SIZE   = argv[2];
    NUMBER = argv[3];

    if (strcmp(OPTION,"-b") == 0)
    {
        number = str_to_ull(NUMBER,2);
        print_ull(number,10);
        return 0;
    }

    if (strcmp(OPTION,"-d") == 0)
    {
        number = str_to_ull(NUMBER,10);
        print_ull(number,2);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Invalid input arguments\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to include leading zeros to the binary outputs and with leading spaces for the decimal outputs?

Comment: Didn't realize I did! opps!

Comment: Sorry, it turns out that it wasn't you, my mistake :) will answer your question in a minute...

Comment: Yes, there is: `int i = 0; while (NUMBER[i++] == '0') printf(" ");`. But it doesn't make sense to do that. For example, how would you represent `0`?

Comment: By casting it? I have been trying some stuff but failing greatly haha the closest I have is to printing out some leading zeros but then it messes up the actual answer...and would there be another way for the print method besides recursion? I need to do some different stuff with the output (for example, having spaces after 4 binary numbers; 0000 0000)

Comment: If you want an iterative print, then you can use this instead: `void print_ull(unsigned long long ull,int base) {int i; char str[64]; if (ull == 0) printf("0"); else {for (i=0; ull>0; i++, ull/=base) str[i] = (char)('0'+ull%base); while (i--) printf("%c",str[i];}}`.

Comment: hmmm...ok I will try something like that. I feel like all of my problems with this program are super elementary so I don't know why I can't figure it out!

Comment: BTW, if you want this **only** for binary numbers (where you add a space after every 4 characters), then you probably need to implement it in a separate function.

Comment: @user3366369: If it's a compilation error, then it's probably the missing `)` at the end of the second `printf`. But I really think that you should learn how to handle compilation errors, which is far easier than handling runtime errors - you simply click on the error, and the compiler brings you to the exact line (or to a nearby line in some rare cases).

Comment: It's not that, I have it compiling and running but it wont put in any spaces, leading spaces, or leading zeros; I have tried doing some modulus stuff, what you suggested, and other things but it all seems to not like me much

Comment: Well, just adding the spaces should be easy. First, print the initial spaces: `for (int j=i; j%4; j++) printf(" ");`. Then, print the inner spaces: `while (i--) {printf("%c",str[i]); if (i%4==0 && i>0) printf(" ");}`.

Comment: hmmm...still not working. not sure what I am doing wrong; I think it is something with the recursive printing that keeps the spaces and leading zeros to work..

Comment: Is there a way to check that the command line argument is indeed binary when it says it is? For example, I would want to print an error message if user input was: ./a.out -b -8 141

Comment: Binary: you need to check `'0' <= NUMBER[i] && NUMBER[i] <= '1'` for each character in `NUMBER`. Decimal: you need to check `'0' <= NUMBER[i] && NUMBER[i] <= '9'` for each character in `NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is simple example code to enter number from command-line and convert that decimal-integer to binary.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Variable declarations.
    int i;  //Holds input decimal number.
    int t;  //Holds temp mod i%2
    int c = 0;  //Holds the bit count.
    char b[2] = "";  //Hold the temp binary bit string to be append.
    char bin[64] = "";  //Holds the final binary string

    //Check if the syntax is proper.
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("\nSYNTAX: binary <decimal>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //Convert the input string parameret into decimal.
    i = atoi(argv[1]);

    //reset the flags.
    t = 0;

    while (i != 0)
    { 
        t = i % 2;
        i = i / 2;
        //convert int decimal (base 10) to string.
        itoa(t, b, 10);
        //Concat to main binary string.
        strcat(bin, b);
        c++;
    } 
    //reverse the string.
    strrev(bin);
    printf("\nBinary: %d(10) = %s(2)\n",i, bin);
    return 0;
}
```